How to properly react to changes from other providers using Riverpod?
currently BatchSizeNotifier reset ProgressNotifier when it changes, but I would like ProgressNotifier to reset itself when BatchSizeNotifier changes by listening to it, but it doesn't seem to work.
How to properly react to changes from other providers using Riverpod?
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:zero_loss_compress/convertion_stats.dart';

final batchSizeProvider = NotifierProvider<BatchSizeNotifier, int>(() {
  return BatchSizeNotifier();
});

final progressProvider = NotifierProvider<ProgressNotifier, int>(() {
  return ProgressNotifier();
});

class BatchSizeNotifier extends Notifier<int> {
  @override
  int build() {
    return 0;
  }

  void setBatchSizeAndResetConversionState(
    int batchSize,
    WidgetRef ref,
  ) {
    state = batchSize;
    // ref.read(progressProvider.notifier).reset(); try to remove this call by listening from ProgressNotifier build
    ref.read(convertionStatsStateProvider.notifier).state =
        ConvertionStats(0, 0);
  }
}

class ProgressNotifier extends Notifier<int> {
  @override
  int build() {
    ref.listen(batchSizeProvider, (previous, next) {
      reset();
    });
    return 0;
  }

  void increment() {
    state = state + 1;
  }

  void reset() {
    state = 0;
  }
}


To properly react to changes from other providers in Riverpod, you can utilize the ref.listen method. However, there are a few adjustments needed to ensure the ProgressNotifier listens to changes in BatchSizeNotifier correctly.
So two things:
ref.listen Location - You cannot use ref.listen in the build method directly because build is designed to return the initial state. Instead, you can use ref.listen in the constructor of the Notifier.
Avoid Direct Dependency in Build - If you want ProgressNotifier to react when BatchSizeNotifier changes, you can establish a listener in the constructor or another initialization method.
Hope this helps. Let me know if it doesn't!

thanks your explanation moving ref.listen didn't solve my issue.
class ProgressNotifier extends Notifier<int> {
  ProgressNotifier() {
    ref.listen(batchSizeProvider, (prev, next) {
      reset();
    });
  }

  @override
  int build() {
    return 0;
  }

  void increment() {
    state = state + 1;
  }

  void reset() {
    state = 0;
  }
}

LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_element@37511105' has not been initialized.)
I think batchSizeProvider is not initialize yet
can you modify my code so I can understand how to do it?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
